# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler' in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, event-handling, keypress

I'm trying to make a textBox that accepts only numbers.

```
    private void depositTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
            (e.KeyChar != '.'))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
```

This is in the designer.

```
    this.depositTextBox.KeyPress += new System.EventHandler(this.depositTextBox_KeyPress);
```

Additional error.

```
    No overload for 'depositTextBox_KeyPress' matches delegate 'EventHandler'
```

Comment: What if the decimal separator is not a point? What if multiple separators are typed? What if only the sign is typed so no valid number can be parsed? What if something is pasted by hotkeys/Windows messages/context menu? All of the numbers-only-textboxes I saw were flawed and clunky. Instead, use validation. Simpler and also cleaner. Or simply bind the `TextBox` to an int/float/decimal property or `DataTable` column and everything will just work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

That's because [KeyPress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=net-5.0) is an event of type `KeyPressEventHandler` not an `EventHandler` as you try to use (see `new System.EventHandler` in your code).

Either use the correct type with `new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler` or, which is much easier, just assign the method directly with `this.depositTextBox.KeyPress += this.depositTextBox_KeyPress;`

To be more precise, the error actually happens inside the `System.EventHandler` constructor, as it expects a method of the signature `void methodName(object, EventArgs)` while your method is of signature `void mehtodName(object, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)`